# Android application with two entry points. How to know which is clicked by user on onCreate() of application object

Tags: android

I have a android application with two entry points. i.e. I have two icon on home screen but internally they are single application.

I want to know how i can set some parameter in Application object depending on the icon click.

More precisely, I want to maintain a scope variable which will keep information of the scope of my application based on what icon user has clicked. Based on this my common screens will behave differently for both of this entry points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application has `getApplicationInfo()` and ApplicationInfo has [`loadIcon(PackageManager pm)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#loadIcon%28android.content.pm.PackageManager) - 
Retrieve the current graphical icon associated with this item. Is it enough?

I think also that [`getPackageName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29) could be used, too, but the author should use different names for both variants of application.

Comment: Erm. `Context` has [getApplicationInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationInfo%28%29). And ApplicationInfo doesn't have a loadIcon(afaik), it has [loadDescription()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#loadDescription%28android.content.pm.PackageManager%29). That is again most unlikely to help is cause. Sorry, if I'm wrong somewhere. :-)

Comment: It is inherited method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#loadIcon(android.content.pm.PackageManager)

Comment: Oh right. Well then this seems a good answer. +1 . Need to delete mine, will mislead the OP. :-)

Comment: I think also that http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName() could be used, too, but the author should use different names for both variants of application. I do not insist, I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Do not throw away your answer - it has references on useful info, close by theme. Very often somebody is searching for something rare and finds not the exact answer, but something *similar*. And sometimes it is the only help. IMHO.

Comment: I think it will be misleading information. I'd prefer it deleted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12371/discussion-between-gangnus-and-kazekage-gaara)

Comment: Thanks Gangnus.. I am using loadLabel in my case, since icon of both entry point is same.

Comment: Of course, you can make any parameter the distinguishing one. Only don't forget to mark the answer :-)